# WCF client should InnerChannel be disposed?

Tags: c#, wcf

Does the `Innerchannel` object be disposed manually?

```
var client = new MyClient();
client.CallServer();
client.InnerChannel.Dispose()
client.Close()
```

or is this enought?

```
var client = new MyClient();
client.CallServer();
client.Close()
```

`BaseClient<T>` class implements IDisposable - but it does so explicit

e.g: `void IDisposable.Dispose()`

Does this mean that i should *not* manually call `Dispose()` on the client?

I'm a bit confused - any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to dispose the `InnerChannel` of your client explicitly. When you call `Close` on your Client it will close and dispose the `InnerChannel` for you.

You can manually call `Dispose` on your client, cause it will call the `Close` method of your client.
The only thing you need to do is assign your client to an `IDisposable`. Otherwise you cannot call Dispose directly on your client.

Or you can use your client with a using-statement

```
using (var client = new MyClient()) {
  client.CallServer();
}
```

Comment: Sounds right to me, but do you have some documentaion on that?

Comment: @JensKloster check the MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576141.aspx as a starting point

Comment: I did :) - it doesn't quite say. It is not mentionsed on the `InnerChannel` property, nor on the `Close` or `Dispose` methods. Having said that - I'll still accept your anwser. Thank you sir.

Comment: @JensKloster you can also decompile the .NET assemblies using a decompiler such as dotPeek. Then you will see that `Dispose` calls `Close` and that the `Close` method will dispose the `InnerChannel`

Comment: I actually did that to, but got lost :-/